# Creating an array to manage terrain

Tags: xna, c#

I want to create random terrain for my game in XNA but i have a problem:

Lets say my game window size is 500X500, so potentially I want an 500 by 500 array right?

But here is the problem, my terrain texture is lets say 5X5, and my player is 20X20.
So using the array isn't that good after all because I want to use collision detection on the player and the terrain so he wont fall through.

Maybe an array of ***[500/terrainTexture.Width,500/terrainTexture.Height]*** would be better?

Is there a way to fix my problem so i can use collision detection between the player and the terrain?

thanks!

(the terrain is like terraia or 2D minecraft)

Comment: This issue is already resolved by any tiled platformer game engine. It all depends on the density In this case I am guessing dense so yeah, saving a 2d-array of tiles will work. Some engines that have a very sparse design might prefer a hash instead.

Comment: What do you mean by a hash?
and can you give me some sort of a lead how should i implement this? I need to build it form scratch.

Comment: No, you don't. A Hash already exists in XNA. If you want to learn how tiled games code works before you copy it, you can check some tutorial and open-source. Once you start you"ll have more specific question but really  I think you should use as much existing code as possible unless you are into coding more than into making games.

Comment: They even have some tutorials and kits for this purpose: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FR7crO2xq8A

Answer (score 1):

To help solve your problem, you need to first understand the concept of a camera (in terms of game dev).

The idea is to separate conceptual coordinates which is where your objects are in the game world from rendering coordinates which is where objects are drawn on the screen. In other words, you will need some logic that will transform world coordinates to rendering coordinates which is usually encapsulated in the form of some `Camera` object. For example, your game's character might at a corner of the map while you want to draw the character in the middle of the screen. The camera is essentially where you are viewing the game world from.

See a [2D Camera Tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/237979-2d-camera-in-xna/) and [MSDN docs on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197901.aspx).

Comment: @NaorHadar What XiaoChuan is suggesting is that you decouple/disengage your idea of what size your terrain is (or any object in your world, for that matter), from how it is perceived through the screen. If you consider that in real life, a bus can appear tiny or large based on how far away your eye is from the bus, you can see that _representation_ / _perception_ of an object is irrelevant to the idea of what that object _is_.

Comment: I have read the articles but I still don't get how should i implement the terrain build and how should i manage the collision between the player and the terrain.